# calculating how much two strings are similar?

Tags: c++, algorithm, processing-efficiency, cpu-speed

I have a function that calculates the variance of the two given strings.  Is there a faster method (or algorithm) to do such thing?

Please keep in mind that every letter of my strings are all loaded with DNA, which means that these are one of the A or T or C or G:

```
unsigned __int8 dis(char* FirstString, char* SecondString)
{
    unsigned __int8 distanceIndex = 0;
    for (unsigned __int8 i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (FirstString[i] != SecondString[i])
            distanceIndex++;
    }
    return distanceIndex;
}
```

Comment: How about Levenshtein Distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance  ?

Comment: You may want to use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) like spell checkers do.

Comment: does Levenshtein  provide a better time complexity?, can anyone implement such method, like i do in the above?

Comment: if you only have 4 possible values per element, you can use a more compact representation of your sequence. You can use only 2 bits instead of 8. You may then calculate the hamming distance on that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: I was just trying to figure out where `l` came from, and whether it is intentional that both sequences have identical length, as they value `l` and that loop construct seems to have us assume.

Comment: @WhozCraigthe you could assume that the l is a constant value, which in this case is 13 by the way

Comment: Depending on the compiler and/or target platform, I can _conceive_ that using an explicitly 8-bit int in the loop might possibly be slower than using a natural-size int.

Comment: @TripeHound oh really? :( , how can you tell?

Comment: *`__int8 distanceIndex`*? -- I really hope that your strings are always shorter than 128 characters.

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi If you mean "how can I tell that it will make a difference", then I can't -- just that there's an outside possibility that manipulating 8-bit counters on a 32/64-bit processor could, conceivably, be fractionally slower than using a "natural" 32-bit counter.  If there _was_ a difference, I'd expect it to be very marginal, but if you've identified this routine as a bottle-neck, and are calling it enough times that fractional improvements might make a difference, then it _might_ be worth profiling alternatives.

Comment: @Wolf I am sure, my strings are always 13

Comment: @TripeHound right,so you cannot tell for sure, huh? i guess the only way to find out is to benchmark it

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi Do you lots of these comparisons?

Comment: @Wolf No, i don't, but this is bottleneck function for my current project that i'm working on, and i need it to be as fast as possible

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi Correct -- at the level you're talking (e.g. the algorithm isn't demonstrably inefficient), benchmarking one idea vs. another is the only way to tell for sure (and that's benchmarking in as realistic environment as you can.  Running that function over 13-character strings will "normally" be "so quick as to be ignorable" and must only be significant in your app (where, I guess, it's being called thousands or millions of times).

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi I found [a fast compare applicable for DNA sequences of fixed length up to 16](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38491405/2932052)  :) BTW: you should better add the fixed length 13 to the question, this is an important point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I still doubt that the string comparison is really [the bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460743/calculating-how-much-two-strings-are-similar#comment64356585_38460743) of your project, I couldn't resist to take up the challenge...

All of your sequences are [13
chars long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460743/calculating-how-much-two-strings-are-similar?noredirect=1#comment64355311_38460743). DNA sequences contain only the letters `ATCG`, which can be encoded within 2 bits. You can store each DNA sequence within a 32 bit value, letting the computer do the comparison in parallel:

- XOR-combine the values to get bit differences
- shift and OR-combine AND-normalized subsets (odd bits, even bits) to
  transform bit differences into nucleobase differences
- count the set bits to obtain the DNA sequence distance

Depending on the computer architecture there may be a bit count function
implemented in the CPU. More details have the answers to the question: [How
to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit
integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Here is the core function:

```
int distV(const unsigned va, const unsigned vb)
{
    const unsigned x = va ^ vb;
    const unsigned bn = ((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1 ) | (x & 0x55555555);
    return __builtin_popcount(bn);
}
```

See the [full GCC-4.3.2 demo](https://ideone.com/FdrWll) that uses sequences of length 16. I measured a performance increment of factor 4 for the comparison itself (excluding the encoding).

Comment: It's a really good idea to compress the nucleobase string thanx for mentioning, but can you explain how to do the comparision  in parallel?

Comment: It's bit operations. Did you have a look at the demo? I'll add the core function for comparison to my answer.

Comment: That would be great :)

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi it's **already added**, see the `distV` function: it compares 32 bits (that is 16 nucleobases in the given encoding) in parallel.

Comment: oh sorry, I see, that's truly fastest,but it's take amount of time for encode though, is it worth it, that i re-implement all the project to work with encoded strings?

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi It depends on your actual needs. The encoding has its cost of course. But (I did not measure it) I guess, it's nearly as cheep as a normal string compare. There can be **another benefit** for your purpose: It **saves memory** (4 bytes instead of at least 13 bytes) and therefore most probably also faster (Less disk swapping. Aligned memory access on a 32 bit machines). By the was, concerning your *`truly fastes`*, I bet there are even faster alternatives out there... ;)

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi I measured the time consumption for encoding: on my machine it takes 168% of the time used for string comparison (I built a 32bit program).

Answer (score 1):

This is an O(n) algorithm.

The most efficient algorithm to compare equality (or distance in this case) between two strings is O(n).

Comment: what about Levenshtein and hamming distance?, is this algorithm better than those?

Comment: Levenshtein complexity is O(n + d^2) where d is the distance. Hamming distance is O(n) as well.

Comment: The comment was added after the answer was already posted, but it doesn't really make much sense talking about O(N) when N is just 13, so algorithm complexity, even if right in general, doesn't answer to this question IMHO.

Comment: I have no idea why OP is even worrying about complexity when n=13. But the above answer is *general*.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi there is really some place for optimisation in this given case (low n), depending on the operand's width of the architecture, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38491405/2932052).

Answer (score 0):

You could make it slightly faster by avoiding the random accessing done by indexing, you only actually need sequential accessing of the string.

I'm not sure whether a compiler could optimise that for you though.

Comment: my compiler, can optimize that, there is not difference between these two

Answer (score 0):

You can spare the `if`:

```
unsigned __int8 dis(char* FirstString, char* SecondString)
{
    unsigned __int8 distanceIndex = 0;
    for (unsigned __int8 i = 0; i < l; i++)
       {
            distanceIndex += FirstString[i] != SecondString[i];
       }
    return distanceIndex;
}
```

but I doubt if this significant

Comment: it is not correct, the distanceIndex just get incremented every time

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi I just tried it and it work fine for me (I used regular `unsigned int` if that's matter)

Comment: it just give me wrong answer,just some weird number, and i don't know what's the problem with your approach:(

Comment: @ShaheenZahedi  you can see my live code [here](http://ideone.com/FMhxuW)